# multisig vs singlesig

Tags: wallet, address, security, private-key, multi-signature

Due to the Ledger debacle I have purchased a Coldcard hardware wallet. I made this decision partly based on watching [the Antonopoulos live stream last week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9scIevuymZM). Until now I have backed up my bitcoin on a single seed phrase stamped in metal. There are two copies which are securely stored at two different locations. I’m thinking of upping my security regarding the seed phrase.

My question is, does a 12 word ‘two of two’ multisig offer more protection than a singlesig 24 word? I would be storing the ‘two of two’ seed phrases together. Of course if the ‘two of two’ are found it’s game over. But, as talked about in Antonopoulos’ live stream I want to keep things relatively simple. What I am trying to achieve is a heightened level of security regarding vulnerabilities from a singlesig; whether that is in the form of a hack or some future unknown weakness in Coldcard’s TRNG.

Comment: The difference between 12 and 24 words seems to be a common misconception going around bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118558/… it is completely irrelevant as to whether or not you are using multi-sig as well. Basically it is not useful to make comparisons across setups with different numbers of seed words because they will produce pubkeys that require the same number of rounds to crack in Pollards rho algorithm regardless of the input entropy. The seed words also don't restrict the usage of multi-sig in any way.